# Hide/Show button not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with below code, I created a button to show and hide a div. 
I applied some jQuery to it.
Everything seems to be fine to me but it is still not working, I cannot seem to find why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#closeButton").click(function() {
    if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Close Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").hide();
      $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer");
    }
    if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Open Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").show();
      $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron" id="topDrawer">
  <span id="appName">App Name<span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Close Drawer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="closeButton" />
```

Comment: @zakariaacharki Never correct code in a question. The incorrect syntax could very well lead to (or contribute to) the issue that the question is about. Edits for formatting or to change the wording of the question to make it more clear are great.

Answer (score 3):

You need an else block. Your two if conditions are running one after another.
Use

```
if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Close Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").hide();
      $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer");
}
else if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Open Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").show();
      $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use else in your condition like :

```
if ( $("#closeButton").val() === "Close Drawer" ) {
  $("#topDrawer").hide();
  $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer");
} else {
  $("#topDrawer").show();
  $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
}
```

Else the both statements will be triggered and the button will toggle twice and return to the default case `Close Drawer` and you can't notice that since it will change in milliseconds.

**NOTE :** You could use `else` without the second if statement, check the working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#closeButton").click(function() {
    if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Close Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").hide();
      $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer");
    } else if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Open Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").show();
      $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron" id="topDrawer">
  <span id="appName">App Name</span>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Close Drawer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="closeButton" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's an `<input>` and does have value

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl just noticed that... updated my post

Comment: Checking value twice seems redundant

Comment: Yes, Just for the case if there's a third value, else we could use simple `else`. (updated)

Answer (score 2):

Your `<span>` element was not properly closed and your `if` statement was not set up as an `if/else`, so both `if` statements were running. But, nothing would happen if neither condition was true.

Having said that, the **[JQuery `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** method along with a **[JavaScript ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)** makes this much simpler and eliminates the need for `if/else` in the first place.

You should also use the JQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method to set up your event handlers as recommended by the JQuery team.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#closeButton").on("click", function() {
    $("#topDrawer").toggle("slow");  // Toggle the visibility of the element
    // Change the vale of the element based on what it is now
    $("#closeButton").val() === "Close Drawer" ?  
       $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer") : $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron" id="topDrawer">
  <span id="appName">App Name</span>
</div>
<input type="button" value = "Close Drawer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="closeButton">
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your condition like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#closeButton").click(function() {

    if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Close Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").hide();
      $("#closeButton").val("Open Drawer");
    }
    else if ($("#closeButton").val() == "Open Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").show();
      $("#closeButton").val("Close Drawer");
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron" id="topDrawer">
  <span id="appName">App Name<span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value = "Close Drawer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="closeButton" />


      <script>

      </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried like this with `else if` block and it is working as you wish. One more thing I used `prop` to set value (thought it doesn't effect your code). Except that everything is same as your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $("#closeButton").click(function() {
   
    if ($("#closeButton").val() === "Close Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").hide();
      $("#closeButton").prop('value', "Open Drawer");
    } else if ($("#closeButton").val() === "Open Drawer") {
      $("#topDrawer").show();
      $("#closeButton").prop('value', "Close Drawer");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron" id="topDrawer">
  <span id="appName">App Name<span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value = "Close Drawer" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="closeButton" />
```